# Acro Package does not bring any output

Tags: errors, acro

I'm trying print a list of acronyms in my thesis by using the acro package. I'm somehow getting the following errors though:

> Argument of \acro_print_list_short:nn has an extra }.
> ...ms[include-classes=abbrev,name={Acronyms}]
>
> Paragraph ended before \acro_print_list_short:nn was complete.
> ...ms[include-classes=abbrev,name={Acronyms}]#
>
> Missing { inserted. ...ms[include-classes=abbrev,name={Acronyms}]
>
> Missing } inserted. ...ms[include-classes=abbrev,name={Acronyms}]

Here is what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass [
a4paper
, titlepage
, twoside
, openright
]{book}

\usepackage[linedheaders, eulerchapternumbers, dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{acro}

\input{glossary}

\begin{document}
    \chapter*{Acronyms and Symbols}
    \acsetup{extra-style=comma}
    \printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name={Acronyms}]

    \chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

The glossary file contains the acronyms:

```
\acsetup{first-style=short}

\DeclareAcronym{AC}{short = AC, long = Alternating Current, class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{Al}{short = Al, long = Aluminum, class = abbrev}
```

And I'm calling them in the text with \ac{AC} and \ac{Al}.

Does anybody have any idea how this can be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

classicthesis redefines the description label and inserts a rather fragile command based on commands from the package soul. This explodes when the description label is a rather complicated command as in the list created by printacronyms. You can avoid that soul is used by using the option pdfspacing or by redefining `\descriptionlabel`:

```
\documentclass []{book}

\usepackage[linedheaders, eulerchapternumbers, dottedtoc,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{acro}

\acsetup{first-style=short}
\acsetup{extra-style=comma}
\DeclareAcronym{AC}{short = AC, long = Alternating Current, class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{Al}{short = Al, long = Aluminum, class = abbrev}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Acronyms and Symbols}


%\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace*{\labelsep}{#1}} 
\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name={Acronyms}]

\ac{AC} and \ac{Al}
\end{document}
```